# Is it true that minimizing the square of the expectation is the same as minimizing the expectation of the square?

Tags: probability

> Is it true that minimizing the square of the expectation is the same and minimizing the expectation of the square?

Consider a random variable $X_c$ depending on some parameter $c$. Do we have that $$\arg\min_c E[X_c^2] = \arg\min_c (E[X_c])^2$$

This seems very natural.

Comment: Should one of those be "expectation of the square"?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No:  for $c\ge1$ say, let $X_c$ be uniformly distributed in the interval $[-c,c]$. Then $E[X_c^2]$ is positive (I think $\frac c3$) while $E[X_c]^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not equivalent. For example, you could imagine a situation where there are only two possible values of $c$. For one value of $c$, $X_c$ is always equal to $1$. For the other value of $c$, $X_c$ is equal to $1$ with probability $1/2$ and is equal to $-1$ with probability $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no reason that this should be true.  If $X$ is continuous with pdf $f$, what your asking is that
$\big{(}\int x f(x)\ dx\big{)}^2= \int x^2 f(x)\ dx$$
which is likely rarely, if ever, true.